# decoding stripe json with json_decode not working

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have json from stripe and I am trying to decode it json_decode.

I am not getting an error. Just nothing is returning. I am getting the data back from stripe, I just cant decode it.

```
{
   "created":1326853478,
   "data":{
      "object":{
         "amount":4500,
         "card":{
            "country":"US",
            "cvc_check":"pass",
            "exp_month":7,
            "exp_year":2014,
            "fingerprint":"9aQtfsI8a17zjEZd",
            "id":"cc_00000000000000",
            "last4":"9782",
            "object":"card",
            "type":"Visa"
         },
         "created":1322700852,
         "currency":"usd",
         "disputed":false,
         "fee":0,
         "id":"ch_00000000000000",
         "livemode":false,
         "object":"charge",
         "paid":true,
         "refunded":true
      }
   },
   "id":"evt_00000000000000",
   "livemode":false,
   "type":"charge.refunded"
}
```

---

```
// retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');

$event_json = json_decode($body,true);
print_r($event_json);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah. Remove the character that's obscuring any error messages.

Comment: Igancio is referring to the `@` character.

Comment: Also check with `json_last_error()` and/or http://jsonlint.com/, you might have an UTF-8 BOM in there or something.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I ran this:

```
<?php
     $data = '{ "created": 1326853478, "data": { "object": { "amount": 4500, "card": { "country": "US", "cvc_check": "pass", "exp_month": 7, "exp_year": 2014, "fingerprint": "9aQtfsI8a17zjEZd", "id": "cc_00000000000000", "last4": "9782", "object": "card", "type": "Visa" }, "created": 1322700852, "currency": "usd", "disputed": false, "fee": 0, "id": "ch_00000000000000", "livemode": false, "object": "charge", "paid": true, "refunded": true } }, "id": "evt_00000000000000", "livemode": false, "type": "charge.refunded" }';

    $arr = json_decode($data, true);

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

And it worked. So, theoretically you should be able to use:

```
<?php

    $arr = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said, don't use the '@' character because it obscures error messages and makes it harder to debug.

I would also check what version of PHP you have. json_decode() is only available on version 5.2.0 and later.

Answer (score 1):

The `php://input` stream allows you to read raw data from the request body. This data will be a string and depending on what sort of values are in the request, will look something like:

```
"name=ok&submit=submit"
```

This is **not** JSON and therefore won't decode as JSON the way you expect.The `json_decode()` function returns *null* if it can't be decoded.

Where are you getting the JSON you posted above? That is the value you need to pass into `json_decode()`.

If JSON is being passed in the request, like in the instance of callbacks, you would still need to parse that portion out to get just the JSON. If the `php://input` stream gives you **name=ok&submit=submit&json={"created": 1326853478}** then you'd have to parse it out. You can use [this function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#94607) from the PHP manual to seperate the values to work like the `$_POST` array:

```
<?php
   // Function to fix up PHP's messing up POST input containing dots, etc.
   function getRealPOST() {
      $pairs = explode("&", file_get_contents("php://input"));
      $vars = array();
      foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
         $nv = explode("=", $pair);
         $name = urldecode($nv[0]);
         $value = urldecode($nv[1]);
         $vars[$name] = $value;
      }
      return $vars;
   }
?>
```

To use it:

```
$post = getRealPOST();
$stripe_json = $post['json'];
$event_json = json_decode($stripe_json);
```